# Automatic Typing Textarea/input/form in JavaScript

Tags: textarea

I've been searching for a way to make a textarea type inside of itself.  Unfortunately, even with some google searching, I still don't have a clue?  Do you guys know where to start with this?

http://lmgtfy |dot| com is an example, but I'm not sure if they use some other technique...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lmgtfy people are simply using javascript to change the value of the input. Here is a simple jsfiddle showing the same thing:

http://jsfiddle.net/Caut6/1/

Comment: how could I make it type the enter key?

Comment: That example uses a single line text input, so it doesn't display more than one line. For that you would want to use a textarea instead. If what you're really asking is how you 'send' the form, that is totally different javascript altogether. I've never needed to do that from plain javascript, but any of the big libraries (mootools, jquery) have functions for sending forms in various ways. That is probably best explained in its own question though.

Comment: I had to look it up, but it is apparently quite easy: http://jsfiddle.net/Caut6/6/

Answer (score 1):

LMGTFY uses javascript.  If you visit the site using chrome or some other browser with a debugger, you should be able to pause javascript execution and check out how they do it, then roll or copy your own version.

In Chrome, the pause button is under the Scripts area.  Their `bundle.js` files appears to host the JS you are looking for, it is around 1000 lines of code, but you should be able to see the few functions you need to borrow their implementation.

Hope this helps.